# Sql: Multiple keywords search for complaints data set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dictionary, keyword-search

I am working on a complaints data-set & I am looking for matching keywords from the keyword dictionary against the data-set.

**Here is the keyword dictionary -**

Sample Keyword Dictionary

**-------------------------**

Debit Card

Credit Card

ATM

Loans

**Sample data-set -**

[image]

**And, Sample Output -**

[image]

That is, I would like the keywords from the keyword dictionary to be matched against the "complaint description" column in my data-set. And, I would like only the matched keywords to show up in the "Keywords Matched" column & count of total keywords matched in the "Count" column.

This is just a sample & my actual data-set is huge plus it might involve "Complaint Description" in foreign language as well. Can you help me on how to go about it?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: We could probably "Can you help me on how to go about it?" however, it is not clear what it is you are trying to do. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Just made an edit to the problem description. I hope its clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume your sample data table is `[Sample Data-set]` and your have your keywords saved in a table called `[Keyword]` (with column name `Keyword`). Try this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT Detail.*, [Keywords Matched] = STUFF((select ',' + Keyword
    FROM KEYWORD as b
    WHERE Detail.[Complaint Description] like '%' + b.Keyword + '%'
    ORDER BY Keyword DESC
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1,'')
FROM [Sample Data-set] as Detail
GROUP BY Detail.BranchID, Detail.Portfolio, Detail.[Complaint Description]
)
SELECT *, len([Keywords Matched]) - len(replace([Keywords Matched], ',','')) + 1 as [Count]
FROM CTE
GROUP BY  BranchID, Portfolio, [Complaint Description], [Keywords Matched]
```